# How to solve the problem of running many main() functions in VS2015？

Tags: visual-studio-2015, program-entry-point

I am studying data structure and running code in VS2015, but because one project can only have one main(). It is very trouble to solve many exercises at one time. I have to create a new project again.

So, can U solve the problem?

Comment: You can only have one `main()`. There cannot be more than one. If you need more than one, start a new program. You can solve more than one problem and still use one `main()`. Put your solutions into functions, and call those functions from that single `main()`.

Comment: It is not very obvious why this is a problem, trying to debug two distinct programs at the same time is not exactly practical.  Guessing: you can create as many projects in a solution as you want.  Use File > Add > New Project.  Switch between them with right-click > Set as Startup Project.  Or if you really want to multitask like that then just startup VS again, you're not stuck with running only one instance.